# pass value inside a variable to this.state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am stuck on a certain project. In this project i want to pass a value in a variable to this.state. ie,

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state= {name: variable_value };
}
```

ie.,

```
 variable_value = obj["name"]; //value accesed from a JSON object.
```

I want to achieve something like this. so that i can access the value in the variable_value like,

```
this.state.name;
```

A thanks in advance.

Comment: It works like that by default. Have you even tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.setState` to set the value

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state= {name: ''};
}

somefunction = () => {
    this.setState({name: obj['name']})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the state like this

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state= {name: ''};
}
```

and access the state like

```
this.state.name
```